# How to add string to MYSQL database, and deleting last character of string in it using php?

Tags: php, mysql, string

I want to *add* the string `,'2')` to a row in my database. The current string in the database looks like this: `('1','42','2122','3')`
If I was to add it normally, this would be the result: `('1','42','2122','3'),'2')`. 
How can I delete the last character of the string, that is already in the database, so it will end up like this: `('1','42','2122','3','2')`
I tried using `concat` and (sub)`str_replace`, but that did not give me the desired result.

Is this possible using SQL only, without first fetching the record and updating it?

Comment: have you tried: https://www.google.pl/search?q=php+delete+last+char ?

Comment: Of course :) But I only came up with the named solutions. How to trim the last string of a string you pass and not one that is already inside the database.

Comment: You want to to delete the last char in db? Thought you want the string ('1','42','2122','3') to preprare an sql insert statement ... Still you can retrieve it from db, delete in PHP and update back with the correct string.

Comment: No, like I said: The string is already inside database and I want to add the ,'2')

Comment: OK, than the easiest way is to select the value from db, `rtrim` the last character, append the new string and update in the DB. Some could suggest triggers, but thats too much for such a simple problem ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can use the **replace** function of mysql

This function is pretty much similar to 'Find-Replace' dialog box found in editors. This would replace all occurrences of 'FIND_String' with 'REPLACE_String' in 'String_Expression'

**Example** - `Select REPLACE ('Vipin', 'i', 'X')`
**Output** - VXpXn
**Syntax:** `Replace ( 'String_Expression', 'FIND_String', 'REPLACE_String' )`

docs: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-select-replace/

In your case, if you have only one *closing bracket* then you can use the following query to update you table..

**PHP code**

```
$newString = ",'2')";

$sql = "UPDATE <tableName> SET <fieldName> = replace(<fieldName>, ')', ". $newString .")";
```

Well keep in mind this will replace every instance of `')'` to `$newString` so this solution will work only if there are only one closing bracket in the end.

Answer (score 4):

```
$result = rtrim($string, ')');
```

http://php.net/manual/pl/function.rtrim.php

Comment: this would remove multiple )'s if any at the end of the string and not only the last character.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this solution. I am going to try that now. To clarify: $string is the one from the database, correct?

Comment: Yep. This will remove the las ")" , then you can append waht you want.

Comment: I am trying it like this, but it doesn't work as of now. Do you maybe now where my error is?  $res= mysql_query("SELECT Favoriten FROM $DB_Table WHERE Name = $name") or die(mysql_error());

   $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
      
      $res = rtrim($row['Favoriten'], ')');

Comment: $res= mysql_query("SELECT Favoriten FROM $DB_Table WHERE Name = $name") or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 3):

```
$rest = substr("abcdef", 0, -1);  // returns "abcde"
```

then use '.' to add the rest.

Answer (score 2):

If i am not getting you wrong...

```
$str = "('1','42','2122','3'),'2')";

$new_str = str_replace( ')' , '' , $str) . ')';

// $new_str -- ('1','42','2122','3','2')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$oldtuple = "('1','42','2122','3')";
$newvalue = ",'2')";
$newtuple = substr($oldtuple, 0, strlen($oldtuple)-1).$newvalue;
```

Now if you type
 
`echo $newtuple;`
you should see the following output:
 
`('1','42','2122','3','2')`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if MySQL can do this too, but in PHP I would do something like this":

```
$string = //get your string from database
$stringtoadd = ",'2')";


$string = substr_replace($string ,"",-1);
    $newstring = $string.$stringtoadd;
//put $newstring in database
```

substr_replace will replace the last character with "" (nothing).

Answer (score 1):

That's your query

`UPDATE TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME = REPLACE(FIELD_NAME, ')', ',YOUR_NUMBER_HERE)')`